# Evaluating a tricky exponential function integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am trying to evaluate the following integral 
$$
I = \int_0^t s^{2\alpha - 1} \exp\left(\frac{i \sqrt{2} \left(t^{2 \alpha + 1} - s^{2 \alpha + 1}\right)}{ 2 \alpha + 1}\right)\mbox{d}{s}
$$
where $0 \le \alpha \le 1$.

I am not quite sure how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this helps in any way, but the expression inside the "exp" is $\int_s^t x^{2\alpha}dx$.

Comment: @martycohen , Thank you I did not know that. I think I might revise my question and provide more context, may be there is a way around this integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $s^{2\alpha+1}=w$. Then
$$
I = \int_0^t s^{2\alpha - 1} \exp\left(\frac{i \sqrt{2} \left(t^{2 \alpha + 1} - s^{2 \alpha + 1}\right)}{ 2 \alpha + 1}\right)\mbox{d}{s}=(1+2\alpha)^{-1}\exp\left(\frac{i\sqrt{2}t^{2\alpha+1}}{2\alpha+1}\right)\int_0^{t^{2\alpha+1}}\frac{dw}{w^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}} \exp\left(\frac{-i\sqrt{2}w}{2\alpha+1}\right)
$$
$$
=(1+2\alpha)^{-1}\exp\left(\frac{i\sqrt{2}t^{2\alpha+1}}{2\alpha+1}\right)\times$$
$$\left[2^{-\frac{\alpha}{2 \alpha+1}} t^{2\alpha} \left(\frac{i t^{2 \alpha+1}}{2 \alpha+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2 \alpha+1}-1} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{2 \alpha}{2 \alpha+1}\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{2 \alpha}{2 \alpha+1},\frac{i \sqrt{2} t^{2 \alpha+1}}{2 \alpha+1}\right)\right)\right]\ .
$$
I checked with Mathematica and it seems to work.